# cannot copy text with double click from table in html

Tags: html, angular, html-table

I have a web application build in Angular. 
In this application there is a html page which display data:

```
 <tr *ngFor="let orderData of currentOrders" (click)="toggleSelectOrder($event, orderData)" class="pointer">
                        <td>
                            <div class="table-row-content">
                                <i class="checkboxes fa icon" [ngClass]="{'fa-check-square-o': orderData.isSelected,
                               'fa-square-o': !orderData.isSelected}"></i>
                                <span class="cell-with-checkbox-text">
                                    {{(orderData?.sapOrder?.orderAddress) || 'NO_DATA' | translate}}
                                </span>
                            </div>
                        </td>
                        <td class="text-left">
                            {{orderData?.sapOrder?.projectName || 'NO_DATA' | translate}}
                        </td>
                        <td class="text-center">
```

When viewing the data in the application, users want to double click on the data field to select the data and then copy the selected data. 
This is not possible at the moment. I can't select it.

Any ideas how to make this possible?

Br,
Lino

Comment: I think double click can't possible in this scenario because there is already a click event(toggleSelectOrder) on your "tr". So when user dobule clicks to row toggleSelectOrder  fires first!!!

Comment: @Mehmet can use both events

Answer (score 0):

add doubleclik method in HTML templete

```
<tr *ngFor="let orderData of currentOrders" (dblclick)="nameMethod(orderData)" (click)="toggleSelectOrder($event, orderData)" class="pointer">
```

if you need also row number in ngFor add `let i=index` and pass `i` inside method paramiters